# actionfunction actionstatus IE8/IE9 problem

Tags: actionfunction, internet-explorer

I have a page like that

```
<apex:form>
<apex:actionStatus id="blockInterface" onstop="$.unblockUI();" onstart="$.blockUI();" />
 <apex:commandButton status="blockInterface" oncomplete="init();" rerender="table,ratecardsPanel" value="Add column" action="{!add}"  /> 
  </apex:form>
```

this page have no header and this seems to be the problem.

The only fix that works for me is add this

```
<div id="ieBrowserFix" style="display:none;">
  <apex:sectionHeader title="IE" subtitle="BrowserFix" />
</div>
```

Anyone knows a better fix?

Comment: What exactly is the problem caused by the lack of a section header?

Comment: BTW, Salesforce will be dropping support for IE7 & IE8 January of 2015.  I know that's a ways off, but remember it's 2013.  Get your company on the modern-web-browser bandwagon.   (http://www.cloudsuccess.com/blog/ie-7-8-not-supported-summer15/)

Comment: Without sectionHeader the browser complains with a javascript error: window.document.getElementById(...) is null or not an object. It seems that the actionStatus isn't rendered or js tries to get elements before the document is ready. P.S.: amatorVitae I agree with you and is the first thing I try to explain to my customer ;)